# How can I remove a Windows directory with rmdir?

Tags: php, windows, directory-permissions

How I can remove a directory with `rmdir` ?

The directory is empty but I can't remove/delete it.

```
$root_dir = "C:/xampp/htdocs/";    
$dir = $root_dir.'tmp/';    
rmdir($dir);
```

Comment: Does PHP and/or Apache have permission to delete?  Windows permissions are far more fine-grained than those on Unix.  Make sure you have `error_reporting` turned all the way up to -1.

Comment: Check the file permissions on that folder, maybe you don't have the right permissions to delete it

Comment: Maybe you have hidden files in it, or you don't have delete permission ?

Comment: Maybe this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1217032/1741542 helps.

Comment: Try the rd command, it may give you more information about the failure.

Answer (score 2):

Important consideration which kept me stunned for a while: Make sure you did not `chdir()` into the directory you want to delete, and if you did, `chdir()` out of it before. You cannot delete the current working directory on Windows.

Comment: Thanks, this was bugging me. However, what's the alternative?

Comment: Just `chdir()` to somewhere else before deletion :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function removedir($dirname)
{
    if (is_dir($dirname))
    $dir_handle = opendir($dirname);
    if (!$dir_handle)
    return false;
    while($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            if (!is_dir($dirname."/".$file))
            unlink($dirname."/".$file);
            else
            {
                $a=$dirname.'/'.$file;
                removedir($a);
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($dir_handle);
    rmdir($dirname);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If permissions aren't an issue, then tmp directory might contain files in it. rmdir only removes empty directories. Use this function to delete directory + all files:

```
function deleteDirectory($dir) {
    if (!file_exists($dir)) return true;
    if (!is_dir($dir)) return unlink($dir);
    foreach (scandir($dir) as $item) {
        if ($item == '.' || $item == '..') continue;
        if (!deleteDirectory($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$item)) return false;
    }
    return rmdir($dir);
}
```

check https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php#91797 for reference :)